# Open Source or Free Substitute to Parallels or Fusion for Mac OS X

Tags: windows, mac-osx, vmware-fusion

Are there any products such as [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/) or [VMware Fusion 2.0](http://store.vmware.com/servlet/ControllerServlet?Action=DisplayPage&Env=BASE&Locale=en_US&SiteID=vmware&id=ProductDetailsPage&productID=82532200) that are free or open source?

I'd like to run Windows from my Mac from (Intel based) Mac OS X but would prefer not to have to buy one of these products.

<del>And if there are no other (or functional) solution, which of these products are superior and why?</del>

**Update**: Not sure it matters, but I mainly want to run **Windows Vista Ultimate**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

It even has seamless mode where you can run your program in a 'native' window on the desktop.

Comment: I had hard time to find what "per-window" virtualization is in Parallels or Fusion, which is not supported on VirtualBox. Would you post a link? Thanks.

Comment: Thats funny, because I use it on Linux command line so that I can run Windows GUI remotely! :)

Comment: Sunny, by per-window I meant seamless. And you are right - you can run seamless with VirtualBox, I forgot about that. Will update my response.

Comment: I replaced Parallels with VirtualBox and am much happier.  The VMs are snappier, not to mention cross platform.  We'll see how Oracle handles this incredible product in the future.

Comment: I use VB on Windows to virtualize Linux servers for testing / playing.

Comment: I heard VirtualBox was acquired by Oracle, does this change their FOSS status? I currently use VirtualBox but if there are other visualization packages I'd be more inclined to switch to one of them given Oracle's handling (or lack-there-of) of MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org). It supports [MacOS](http://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/wiki/Screenshots/VirtualBox_OSX_beta_3.png) and has good reviews.

Answer (score 3):

[virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) works on OS X (intel). It also supports ["seamless" windows](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#seamlesswindows), i.e. opening an windows app on your Mac desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org), it has a nice Remote Desktop setting on beta version which can emulate Unity on Vmware Fusion.

Comment: Thanks but that answer was already give and furthermore it was accepted as the answer....